# Test column pandas dataframe with none type

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing, dataframe

I'm using `pytest` to test my code.

A particular test I'd like to perform is about a function that operates on column in pandas `df`.

A function `foo_fun` is applied to pandas df and it'll add a new column after some operation it should perform on the original dataframe. This function if the input is `None` should return `None`.

Example:

```
def foo_fun(data):
   # create a new column based on INFO column
   txt=list(data.INFO)
   data['NEW_COLUMN'] = ['value' if s is not None else None for s in txt]
   return data

def foo_test():
    fake_data = pd.DataFrame({'ENTITYKEY':['1','2','3','4'],
                              'INFO':['That\'s what she said',
                                      'Questo è un testo in italiano',
                                      'Eso es lo que dice el',
                                      None]})

   fake_data  = foo_fun(fake_data)
   assert(all(fake_data['NEW_COLUMN']==['value','value','value',None]))
```

How can I test this? Test failed, and the problem is the last value, `None`.

Comment: Updated my question with a foo_fun example. Still getting failed test

Answer (score 0):

Use iloc to get last column and then check.

```
if fake_data.iloc[:,-1] != None:
  print("Last Column is not None")
```

Comment: No, it should be inside assert statement.